# .htaccess rewrite all URLs, even if path

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've made some PHP code that will direct the user based on the URL, and I've found some code for htaccess that gives the URL to the index page which lets my code work. However, it's also technically revealing what is a file/folder and what isn't.

If I go to `website.com/somethingrandom/somethingelse`, I'll get a 404 error, whereas going to `website.com/cache/private` will say forbidden.

How would I edit it so that it will act like no files exist, aside from a few select file types, such as images, css, and js files?

Here is the code as it currently stands:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# This rule converts your flat link to a query
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_page_location=$1 [L,NC,NE]
```

Comment: Why are you checking for -d directory existence then?

Comment: Hmm, alright thanks, that half works, I'd only tested it out on files. Removing the `-d` and `-f` bit still says forbidden with files though

Comment: Thanks, already have that there though, here's the file (sorry about not linking the whole thing earlier)  - http://pastebin.com/drhSkL0Z

Comment: Take all the `FilesMatch` parts out and see if it works.

Comment: Those RewriteRules themselves do not generate a 404/403 response. You haven't elaborated on the rest of your environment (not mentioned the .htaccess constrictions in your subdirs). Don't make people guess. That won't result in concrete answers.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to check back and have to dash soon, so will check the answers out once I'm back. As to the responses you mentioned, the PHP code currently handles all 404 errors correctly, and I'm hoping to avoid all server based 403 errors (basically though this question haha), and instead just give each page a 'permissions' value that the PHP code will deal with :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]

# add trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

# If the request is not for known file types
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|gif|php|bmp|png|ico|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]
# This rule converts your flat link to a query
RewriteRule .* index.php?_page_location=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll have to check once I've finished working, but it looks like it may be what I'm after :)

Comment: Hmm, it almost works, but there's a slight problem when following a folder link, not sure if it's something fixable though. It doesn't happen with any files, but if you were to go to `website.com/folder1/folder2`, it then changes the URL to `website.com/folder1/folder2?_page_location=folder1/folder2`.

Comment: Also, this isn't so important, so don't worry about it if you don't know, but how would I override those file types if I was wanting to allow/disallow a certain file?

Comment: I just added a rule to take care of directories. Try my updated rules after completely clearing your browser cache.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide some file or directory, i.e. appear it as not existant, you might redirect with the [`R|redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) flag

```
RewriteRule ^cache/private - [R=404,L]
```

This tells the client, there is no such file named `cache/private` ([404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#404)). Beware though, that this is for *all* clients, even yourself.

To restrict this, you must prefix the rule with some [`RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) or wrap it in some conditional statement like [`If`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#if) or similar.

---

If you want to hide all files, use a "broader" regular expression, like

```
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

This will return a "Not found" for all of your website's URLs. You can also give a set of URLs, like in this

```
RewriteRule ^(?:cache/private|secrets|database) - [R=404,L]
```

which will hide everything below

- cache/private
- secrets
- database

See [Apache - Regular Expressions](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex) and http://www.regular-expressions.info/ for details on how to customize your own pattern.

Comment: I'd prefer something that would work as a 'blanket' over all files, however, that is useful to know for if I need it for anything else, so thanks :)